# substitute words and words with hyphens

Tags: ruby, regex

i will be reading in grammar sentences like

< start >
The   < object >   < verb >   tonight.

and

< start >
< exposition > < conflict > < escape > < conclusion >

< exposition >
< bad-guy > < insane-plan >

I have a function that gets the sentence and should replace whatever has < word >

```
while is_non_terminal?(sentence)
  sentence.sub!(/(<\w+>)/){grammar[[$1]].sample.join(' ')}
end
```

it will read the first sentence fine and replace the words, my problem is that it wont replace words like < bad-guy > because of the hyphen
i tried changing the content the sub! in the function to
sentence.sub!(/(<\w->)/){grammar[[$1]]sample.join(' ')}
I'm not sure how to substitute both regular words with < > and hyphenated words

Comment: You need to make a character set with square brackets: `/(<[-\w]+>)/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex to match both hyphenated and regular words:

`/(\<[a-zA-Z\-]+\>)/`.

This reads: match any repeated sequence of characters between `<` `>` that are either between `a and z`, `A and Z` or the `-` character.

If you are still getting used to regular expressions, the following site may help you practice: https://regex101.com/

Also, keep in mind the tags you entered had spaces after the `<` and before the `>` so you will need to take that into account as well. The following does that.

`/(\< [a-zA-Z\-]+ \>)/`.

Cheers,

Comment: I feel it's worth pointing out that none of the characters in these patterns needs to be escaped with a backslash.

Comment: Indeed. As a general rule, I tend to be a bit paranoid with regex since you never know what engine will run the expression haha